# 404 error in all pages except homepage in the wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404, permalinks

my site zazen.ae I have tried checking the .htaccess file. I disabled, the theme, plugin etc, but nothing is making this issue resolve. However, if I change the permalink to plain, the pages work, but as soon as I make them custom or Post name, it gives a 404 error.

Comment: “I have tried checking the .htaccess file” - and what did it contain? The behaviour you are experiencing could either be caused by an empty/non-existent .htaccess file OR if .htaccess overrides are not enabled on your server OR if mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server.

Answer (score 0):

In the site host (public_html) **.htaccess** file
If it exists, edit it and if it exists, create it and put this code in it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```